# Canvas: DrawImage working perfectly in chrome but not in Mozilla [IndexSizeError : Index or size is negative or greater than the allowed amount]

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

I combined two JQuery libs Jcrop/Iviewer to be able at the same time to zoom and clip an image. code is working on chrome but still have some issues in Mozilla. 
I believe that drawImage causes that error IndexSizeError: Index or size is negative or greater than the allowed amount:

```
$('#crop').Jcrop({
            onChange: imgSelect,
            onSelect: imgSelect
        });

function imgSelect(selection) {
            var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
            var xZoom = $("#image_input").iviewer('info', 'coords', 'true').x;
            var yZoom = $("#image_input").iviewer('info', 'coords', 'true').y;
            var zoom = $("#image_input").iviewer('info', 'zoom', 'true');

                var w_orig = (selection.w * 100) / zoom;
                var h_orig = (selection.h * 100) / zoom;
                canvas.width = w_orig;
                canvas.height = h_orig;

                ctx.drawImage(
                    image,
                    ((selection.x - $("#image_input").iviewer('info', 'coords', 'false').x) * 100) / zoom,
                    ((selection.y - $("#image_input").iviewer('info', 'coords', 'false').y) * 100) / zoom,
                    w_orig,
                    h_orig,
                    0,
                    0,
                    w_orig,
                    h_orig
                );
        }

<div id="image_input" class="viewer"></div> <!--layer 1 zoom-->
<div id="crop"></div><!-- layer 2 crop-->
```

Comment: Hey - did you ever resolve this? I have the exact same issue and can't figure it out. Thx.

Comment: @Eric Yes I finally resolved it ! just try to remove imgSelect call onchange. as follow : $('#crop').Jcrop({
                onSelect: imgSelect
            });

Comment: GSDa, Is this working on a public facing app I can view as a 'demo'?

Answer (score 0):

the issue occurs because for the very first time when you will click on the crop area (or the image) the values for `w_orig` and `h_orig` will be 0 as no actual area as been selected.

What i did to bypass this issue is add a if condition to check these values and when you get them to be 0 you change the value manually. It wont affect the normal cropping as next time when change event is fired you won't get `w_orig` and `h_orig` to be zero and hence if condition will not be true.

```
function imgSelect(selection) {
            var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
            var xZoom = $("#image_input").iviewer('info', 'coords', 'true').x;
            var yZoom = $("#image_input").iviewer('info', 'coords', 'true').y;
            var zoom = $("#image_input").iviewer('info', 'zoom', 'true');

                var w_orig = (selection.w * 100) / zoom;
                var h_orig = (selection.h * 100) / zoom;
                canvas.width = w_orig;
                canvas.height = h_orig;

                if (c.w === 0 && c.h === 0)
                {
                   //set any arbitrary values
                   c.w = 300;
                   c.h = 300;
                }

                ctx.drawImage(
                    image,
                    ((selection.x - $("#image_input").iviewer('info', 'coords', 'false').x) * 100) / zoom,
                    ((selection.y - $("#image_input").iviewer('info', 'coords', 'false').y) * 100) / zoom,
                    w_orig,
                    h_orig,
                    0,
                    0,
                    w_orig,
                    h_orig
                );
        }
```